# Cannot sign-in into the app using Google account

Tags: applications, google-account, google, miui

I have Shiaomi Redmi 5 with Android 8 and MIUI 11.
My Google account is OK - I can use play store, gmail, whatever.
But when some app requires sign-in my phone is stacked on the window

[image]

I.e. I try to tap my account but nothing happens.
Is it possible that there is an Android or MIUI setting that prevents login?
Or it is just a bug?
What to do?
Thanks.

Comment: That screen looks like the oAuth login dialog shown when you want to use your Google account to login into a third party app. It should be displayed in your default web browser. What web browser do you use and do you use add-ons or an ad blocker?

Comment: @Robert I use Chrome and yes I have AdBlocker turned on (at least on my desktop, but they are probably synced). The solution is to make another browser default on Android? I will try.

Comment: @Robert. It works, thanks. I just changed the default browser to MIUI Browser, but any browser except those with AdBlocker will work. You can post it as the answer, I will accept and upvote it.

Comment: Hmm, could you explain more about the AdBlocker? Chrome for Android doesn't support browser extensions, so I'm confused about what it refers to...

Comment: @AndrewT. It looks like Android prevents Chrome (or theoretically any other browser which have AdBlocker on the desktop and synced) from siign-in to apps.  Purely empirical knowledge, not supported by any known documentation :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That screen looks like the oAuth login dialog shown when you want to use your Google account to login into a third party app.

The login page is by default opened in your default web browser (not inside the app itself because the app should not be able to grab your Google credentials when you log-in).

If you can not login, then this is caused by the used web browser or a tool the causes the login to fail on network level.

Possible causes for the web browser to fail:

- Problems with defect cached parts of the web site -> clear web browser cache
- Problems with the web browser itself -> try a different web browser
- Active ad blocker (in the web browser or on Android level if the ad blocker works as a local VPN).